# Tab Bar Controller Inside Nav Controller, is ok?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I need to have a Tab Bar navigation at the end of a branch in the Navigation Controller, as illustrated basically below. (I am using storyboard for structure, and doing everything else programmatically.)

1. Is this acceptable and stable? (Xcode seems to have no objections.)
2. Could I put *another* Tab Bar nav, inside the initial Tab Bar nav, so there would be 3 tiers:
   Nav Controller > Tab Bar > Tab Bar

Thanks for any suggestions and advice.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* do all of this. Xcode won't object. The various view controllers can all contain each other, and will behave (mostly) as you expect.

You might want to think about whether you *should* do all of this. The [View Controller Catalog](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH6-SW1) makes reference to the fact that tab bars always wrap navigation controllers, not the other way around, and similar statements have appeared in the View Controller Programming Guide.

What's more, the particular view controllers that Apple provides generally have an expected user interface, one that users have grown very accustomed to seeing in other apps. Combining multiple tab bar controllers might break those expectations - hierarchical content like that is generally contained in navigation controllers instead. Consider reading through the [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html) before proceeding with this structure.

Comment: Thanks for the concise info. (The Tab Bar nav inside Tab Bar nav would be for sub directories, something seen often in websites for example. And would be styled not using the default buttons.) But I guess I'll have to give it some more consideration. Thanks.

Comment: If you'd like to go with this idea, but don't want to use the built-in system controls, take a look at the new-in-iOS-5 view controller containment API. There's a nice bit about subclassing UIViewController to create a custom container view controller in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81) - you might find that a better approach for your directory structure than hijacking a tab bar controller for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can. Tab bar and Nav controller are both container controller and they can be used to contain any kind of controller: container controller or content controller. Have a look to the [ref](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW1) doc for more info.

Comment: Some slightly conflicting opinions on here about this! But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Not really AFAIK. But you can use a UITabBar NOT a UITabBarController wherever you want.
See this blog article: http://www.alexmedearis.com/uitabbarcontroller-inside-a-uinavigationcontroller/

Comment: Many thanks for the link, he seems to be discussing the same issues as me. Unfortunately he says it is not possible, but seems to have some useful info. Thanks.